# Is react-final-form broken in Safari 17?

Tags: safari, react-final-form, final-form, ios17

We are testing a webview that uses react-final-form on the beta release and it appears to intermittently freeze up all UI interactions.  This appears to be associated with number of keystrokes or other UI events.  Has anybody else confirmed this?  And is this a bug in Safari, or just some sort of side effect?

Comment: I experienced the same thing on both mobile Chrome and Safari. Have been unable to replicate in a desktop browser. :(

Answer (score 3):

We encountered issues with `final-form` in Safari 17 on desktop and mobile. Error message:

> Cannot read property 'active' of undefined

The issue occurred when a form was repeatedly shown and hidden. It seems to have something to do with `Object.assign()`. When we patched the transpiled code, so it always uses Bablel's fallback instead of the native API, the issue was gone.

See also https://github.com/final-form/final-form/issues/186#issuecomment-1735111004

Answer (score 1):

We could not get our webview with react-final-form to work so we had to remove them from the view entirely.  It had something todo with keystroke maximum, and when the max was reached, the entire form was disabled.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by upgrading from final-form version "4.18.6" to "4.20.10".

I know it's an intermittent bug, so I can't be sure. But with 4.18.6, it took me about a handful of attempts to reproduce it (in Safari 17 on macOS Sonoma). And with 4.20.10, I can't reproduce it after trying for 10 minutes under the same conditions.

Found the "solution" via [this comment](https://github.com/final-form/react-final-form/pull/932#issuecomment-1405811477) in a PR that linked issue https://github.com/final-form/final-form/issues/411.